# How to detect if capslock is on or of?

Tags: python

I am trying to check if
caps lock is on or of to know to print either upper letter or lower letter.

```
import keyboard
import time
def pressed_key(key):
    if keyboard.is_pressed(key):
      if "shift+" in key:
        time.sleep(0.08)
        print(key.upper())
      else:
          time.sleep(0.08)
          print(key)


while True:
 pressed_key('shift+d')
 pressed_key('d')
```

I tried with just shift+"key" but it does not owrk how i want it to work.

Comment: Judging by the currently [open issues](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+caps+lock), the `keyboard` module cannot currently detect caps lock state, although there is a [pull request](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard/pull/263) for it so you might be able to check out that specific branch if you really need it.

Comment: The project page says: *"This project is currently unmaintained. It works for many cases, and I wish to pick it up again in the future, but you might encounter some friction and limited features using it."*

Comment: You might want to consider https://pypi.org/project/pynput/ as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Install a hook for the `d` key.  The callback will generate the correct name of the key according to capslock/shift status when it was pressed:

```py
import keyboard

def callback(e):
    print(e.name)

keyboard.on_press_key('d', callback, suppress=True)

input()  # Prevent python from exiting.  Hit enter to quit
```

Output:

```
d                  # caps lock inactive, no shift
d
d
D                  # shift held down, caps lock inactive
D
D
D                  # shift up, caps lock active
D
D
d                  # shift held down, caps lock active
d
d
```

use `keyboard.on_press` for any key instead of a specific one.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ctypes insted of that

```
import ctypes

def is_capslock_on():
    return True if ctypes.WinDLL("User32.dll").GetKeyState(0x14) else False

print(is_capslock_on())
```